# Tengo un problema a la hora de levantar mi proyecto spring boot eclipse, con java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, java-8

[image: Me lanza este error de public key Retrival]

He añadido esto **allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true** en la url para conectar a la base de datos pero no me funciona y me sale otra cosa que no se que es.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
```

Como ven en el error no me soluciona nada en el fichero de configuración de spring boot es el siguiente:

```
#Configuracion de la data base
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BOOKING_RESTAURANT?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.name=root
spring.datasource.password=saladino
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

logging.level.org.hibenate.SQL=debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la información que proporcionas se puede ver que el usuario se esta colocando vacío en el proceso de autenticación con MySql:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)

Esto se debe a que no estas utilizando la propiedad correcta en spring boot `spring.datasource.name=root`, para solucionar el problema remplaza la propiedad a la siguiente:

> spring.datasource.username=root

Como puedes ver la propiedad es `username` y utilizas `user`.

Comment: **Gracias!!** Por tu respuesta me sirvió de mucho.

Comment: Qué bueno que te haya servido de ayuda, de eso se trata esta comunidad, si te ha funcionado como respuesta por favor márcala como respuesta para que tu pregunta aparezca como resuelta  y sirva de guía para otros, tanto en esta como en futuras preguntas.